# Comparing date with next object date in Arraylist not working as expected

Tags: java, date

I've a list of records, where each record has date objects inside it. I'm checking that the first record should have previous dates than the second, and second record dates should be less than 3rd record and so on.. Here is my code..

```
for(int i = 0; i < machines.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < machines.size(); j++) {

            if((machines.get(j).getStrt_Dt().compareTo(machines.get(i).getStrt_Dt()) 
                    * machines.get(i).getStrt_Dt().compareTo(machines.get(j).getStrt_Dt()) >= 0)
                ||
                (machines.get(j).getStrt_Dt().compareTo(machines.get(i).getStrt_Dt()) 
                        * machines.get(i).getStrt_Dt().compareTo(machines.get(j).getStrt_Dt()) >= 0)) {

                throw new Exception("Dates are not as per criteria..");

            }

        }
    }
```

My dates that are coming from the database is:

```
  STRT_DT    END_DT
 ---------- ----------     
 2014-01-01 2014-12-31
 2013-01-01 2013-02-01 (Here the second record is having the date less than first record), this should fail 
 2016-01-01 2016-12-31
 2017-01-01 2017-12-31
 2018-01-01 2018-02-01
```

Am I missing anything? Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Cannot understand why your if statement has the same condition ORed twice?

Comment: `i * i > 0`, even if `i = -1`.

Comment: Because my first record i would be checking with second record j

Comment: Is it enough that start dates come in the right order? Or do you need to check for overlaps in time too? I mean where one end date would come after the following start date.

Comment: Since you have an `ArrayList` you could also use a `listIterator()` to get compare the `next()` and the `previous()` date-pairs.

Comment: @LuCio except if you call `next` and `previous` right after each other, then will return the same element since each of them also changes the position in the list. It can be done, of course, only it’s not quite as trivial as it sounds.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes - you're right. That will not make the code simpler, as I intended by my comment looking at the for-loops used by OP. Looking at your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53299499/2838289) using a for-int-i loop is simple and reads well.

Comment: Your use of the word “less” may be confusing readers. I suggest you edit to use terms like “earlier” and “later”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re over-complicating it. It’s enough to check pairwise entries since if a < b are in the right order and b < c are in the right order, then you already know that a < c are also in the right order.

```
for(int i = 0; i < machines.size() - 1; i++) {
    if (! machines.get(i).getEnd_Dt().before(machines.get(i + 1).getStrt_Dt())) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Dates are not in chronological order");
    }
}
```

I am using “not before” to mean “on or after”. Or to put it another way, I am requiring each start date to come stricty before the next start date, and if it doesn’t, I throw the exception. **Edit:** I didn’t know how to get the end date from your object type, so please substitute the correct getter call where I wrote `getEnd_Dt()`.

If you additionally need to check that each machine has start date and end date in the right order (using the enhanced `for` loop):

```
for (Machine m : machines) {
    if (m.getEnd_Dt().before(m.getStrt_Dt())) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Dates are not in chronological order");
    }
}
```

As an aside, Java naming conventions don’t use underscores in names (except in a `CONSTANT_NAME`), so prefer `getStrtDt` over `getStrt_Dt`. Or even better, `getStartDate`.

That said, Embid123 is correct, you should see if you can replace `Date` with `LocalDate`. The `Date` class has design problems and is long outdated. And despite its name it doesn’t represent a date, but a point in time. `LocalDate` is part of java.time, the modern Java date and time API, which is so much nicer to work with.

The other thing you need is to have your database query sort the entries by start date, then you know you get them in the right order.

### What went wrong in your code?

First, your code is complicated on the border of the unreadable.

Next, when two entries `i` and `j` have start dates in the wrong order, that is, the `j` date is earlier than the `i` date, then `machines.get(j).getStrt_Dt().compareTo(machines.get(i).getStrt_Dt())` is negative and `machines.get(i).getStrt_Dt().compareTo(machines.get(j).getStrt_Dt()` is positive. It’s really the same comparison, only reversed. So the product will be negative, your `>= 0` condition will be false and you will not throw the exception.

Only if two entries have the exact same date (down to the millisecond), `compareTo` returns 0, the product is 0, `>= 0` will be true and your exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thank you. But, I need to validate both start date as well as end date should be less than the next object date.. Do I need to add multiple conditions?

Comment: Can you please modify the example if possible .. I'm not able to get it..

Comment: Thanks first of all.. But  You are just checking the start date should be less than end date.. I requested you that the start date and end date of the first day should be less than start day and end day of the next object in the list. Hence both should be compared with the next level.

Comment: Just use the second loop too. When you have checked that the start date of the first date is not later than the end date, and the end date is before the next start date, and that start date is also before or on the corresponding end date, then if follows that both start and end date of the first thingie are before both start and end date of the second thingie. And so forth for the entire list.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Use the modern [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [`org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) classes to simplify your business logic to basically one line asking if the prior item in the list is not before the current item.

```
if ( 
    ! 
    prior
    .getDateRange()
    .isBefore( 
       current.getDateRange() 
    ) 
) { … handle rule violation … }
```

See also the [correct Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53299499/642706)

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Never use the badly-designed legacy classes. The `java.util.Date` class, despite its name, represents a moment, a date with a time-of-day in UTC. The `java.sql.Date` class pretends to represent a date-only but actually involves a time-of-day and offset as well.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

You can directly parse strings in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: YYYY-MM-DD

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2018-01-23" ) ;
```

For parsing other formats, search Stack Overflow to learn about `DateTimeFormatter`.

### `LocalDateRange`

You seem to using a pair of dates, a start and stop date, in your `Machine` class.

There is a class for that. Add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project to access the [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class. This class has some very useful methods for comparing. Using this class greatly simplifies your code, and makes the intent of your business logic more obvious.

Store your stop/start dates as a `LocalDateRange` object on your `Machine` object.

```
private LocalDateRange dateRange;
```

### Half-Open

Generally the best approach to tracking a span of time is the Half-Open approach. The beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

So a week is defined as starting on one day, such as Monday, and running up to, but not including, the same day of the following week, the next Monday for example. A year starts on January 1 of one year and runs up to, but does include, January 1 of the following year.

Using Half-Open approach would mean defining your example date like the following. Notice how changing the ending date to the year-long values in rows 1, 3, and 4 matches up with your own definition of the apparent month-long values of rows 2 & 5.

```
  STRT_DT    END_DT
 ---------- ----------     
 2014-01-01 2015-01-01
 2013-01-01 2013-02-01 (Here the second record is having the date less than first record), this should fail 
 2016-01-01 2017-01-01
 2017-01-01 2018-01-01
 2018-01-01 2018-02-01
```

### Example class: `Machine`

Here is some example code for your class `Machine`.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Machine {
    private String name;
    private LocalDateRange dateRange;

    // Constructor
    public Machine ( String name , LocalDate start , LocalDate stop ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( name );
        Objects.requireNonNull( start );
        Objects.requireNonNull( stop );
        // TODO: Add checks to validate data, such as dates being not too far into the past or future, and name being non-empty.
        this.name = name;
        this.dateRange = LocalDateRange.of( start , stop );
    }

    // -------|  Accessors  |--------------------------

    public String getName ( ) {
        return this.name;
    }

    public LocalDateRange getDateRange ( ) {
        return this.dateRange;
    }


    // -------|  Object  |--------------------------

    @Override
    public String toString ( ) {
        return "Machine{ " +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                " | dateRange=" + dateRange +
                " }";
    }

}
```

Let's try this class by writing a `main` method.

```
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        List < Machine > machines =
                List.of(
                        new Machine( "one" , LocalDate.parse( "2014-01-01" ) , LocalDate.parse( "2015-01-01" ) ) ,
                        new Machine( "two" , LocalDate.parse( "2013-01-01" ) , LocalDate.parse( "2013-02-01" ) ) ,  // Violates rule, where date-range should be *after* the prior one.
                        new Machine( "three" , LocalDate.parse( "2016-01-01" ) , LocalDate.parse( "2017-01-01" ) ) ,
                        new Machine( "four" , LocalDate.parse( "2017-01-01" ) , LocalDate.parse( "2018-01-01" ) ) ,
                        new Machine( "five" , LocalDate.parse( "2018-01-01" ) , LocalDate.parse( "2018-02-01" ) )
                );
        // Compare
        for ( int i = 1 ; i < machines.size() ; i++ ) { // Using annoying zero-based index counting.
            Machine prior = machines.get( i - 1 );
            Machine current = machines.get( i );
            if ( ! prior.getDateRange().isBefore( current.getDateRange() ) ) {
                System.out.println( "BAD: Machine at index " + ( i - 1 ) + " is not before Machine at index " + i + " ➙ " + prior.getDateRange().toString() + " versus " + current.getDateRange().toString() );
            }
        }
    }
```

When run.

> BAD: Machine at index 0 is not before Machine at index 1 ➙ 2014-01-01/2015-01-01 versus 2013-01-01/2013-02-01

### JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2 and later, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database.

```
LocalDate start = myResultSet.getObject( "start_date" , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using LocalDate? I think it is a good choice for comparing dates. It is since Java 8.

```
    package sample;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class LocalDateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        //of(year, month, day)
        LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.of(2018, 11, 11);

        LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.of(2018, 11, 14);

        long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2);

        System.out.println(daysBetween);
    }
}
```

LocalDate hasn't got any public constructor, you create an object via static factory method. 
By the use of enum ChronoUnit, you get a long value representing days, weeks, or years from one date do second date. If you want to e.g. calculate weeks between, simply replace DAYS with WEEKS.

Now comparing dates is simple, if the value is negative, the first date exceeds the second one.

Documentation of LocalDate: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: I'm not using LocalDate..Its Java.util.Date and this comparision should happen between list of objects

Comment: **This Answer does not address the Question.** The Question asked about working a with a list of items, each having a pair of dates. The Question asked about comparing the pairs of dates, not elapsed days.